# Toggle in using react-strap is opening all toggles at the same time

Tags: reactjs, accordion, reactstrap

My toggle is opening all wraps in the same time when i click in one specific, what's wrong?

```
const SomeData = ({ data, dayNumber }, props) => {
  const Exams = () => {
    const listExams = data.map((item) => (
      <Fragment>
        <Wrap key={item.id}>
          <WrapCard userID={item.userID}>
            <Button color="light" size="lg" block onClick={toggle} style={{ marginBottom: "1rem" }</Button>
            <Collapse isOpen={isOpen}>
              <Card></Card>
            </Collapse>
          </WrapCard>
        </Wrap>
      </Fragment>
    ));
    return listExams;
  };
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const toggle = () => setIsOpen(!isOpen);
};
```

Comment: Your isOpen is global to all the elements in the map. That's why. If you want to make it individual than you will have to provide a state to each element in the map or create a state with all id's of your items and use toggle by id in the global state.

Answer (score 0):

Check out your rendered HTML. You'll see this code block for every item in data:

```
     <Fragment>
        <Wrap key="someID">
          <WrapCard userID="someotherID">
            <Button color="light" size="lg" block onClick={toggle} style={{ marginBottom: "1rem" }</Button>
            <Collapse isOpen=!!---SAME VALUE HERE---!!
              <Card></Card>
            </Collapse>
          </WrapCard>
        </Wrap>
      </Fragment>
```

(Some of the text above in your HTML will look different than what I typed, I only resolved some of it)

The problem is the `---SAME VALUE HERE---` I put in there. They all reference the same `isOpen`. So you need to have many values in your state, one for each item in data. I'm assuming they have a unique ID. so you could use a state that is an empty object, and when you toggle it on: `setIsOpen({...isOpen, item.id: true})` and when you toggle it closed `setIsOpen({...isOpen, item.id: false})`. Then check for each item in data if it should be open. It may look like `<Collapse isOpen={isOpen[item.id]}>` which works only if you want it closed as the default state (if the item is `undefined`) as both `undefined` and `false` are `falsy`.

This would not work if you wanted the default state to be open. Then you'd have to `<Collapse isOpen={typeof isOpen[item.id] === 'undefined' || isOpen[item.id] === true}>`. There would also be more elegant optional chaining answers.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use Collapsible
Use Collapsible

```
npm install react-collapsible --save
yarn add react-collapsible
```

After Installing this modify your code like:

```
import Collapsible from 'react-collapsible';

const SomeData = ({ data, dayNumber }, props) => {
  const Exams = () => {
    const listExams = data.map((item) => (
      <Fragment>
        <Wrap key={item.id}>
          <WrapCard userID={item.userID}>
            <Collapsible trigger = {<span><Button color="light" size="lg" block onClick={toggle} style={{ marginBottom: "1rem" }</Button></span>}>
              <Card></Card>
            </Collapsible>
          </WrapCard>
        </Wrap>
      </Fragment>
    ));
    return listExams;
  };
};
```